# What is the difference between these two Java ClassLoaders and how can I obtain one of them?

Tags: java

Can anybody tell the difference between `ClassLoading$ChainedClassLoader` and `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader` (marked via barely visible yellow highlighter)?

[image]

And how can I obtain the `ClassLoading$ChainedClassLoader`?

Comment: Are we expected to know which class loaders are those in your application? What is the full package for that class? And why are you interested? Is there a problem you are trying to solve? Seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: I'd give a read to this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks for the link, I've already read this. But I'm still a little confused, since (if I'm right) the `Application Class Loader` can be obtained via `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`? `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader` seems to sit inside `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders` where I have no access, but am I correct that this is the `getSystemClassLoader()`? And how can I get the `System Class Loader` at the very top of the chain, right behind the `Bootstrap Class Loader`?